# getting value of second input located inside the form. javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html form

```
echo "<form name='delete_article_form".$row['id']."' action='sources/public/article_processor.php' method='POST' >";
echo "<input name='processor_switcher' id='processor_switcher' type='hidden' value='delete_article'><input name='article_id' id='article_id' type='hidden' value='".$row['id']."'><a class='delete_button' href='#'>".$s_delete[$lid]."</a>";
echo "</form>";
```

Now here is jquery code

```
$('.delete_button').live('click',function(){
article_id = ???????
        alert(article_id);
    });
```

What should I do to get the value from input named "article_id"?
Problem is that I have several such forms on my page so I must use THIS statement.
 `input=$('input',this).val();` will not help cause there are 2 inputs.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
var article_id = $(this).closest('form').find('input[name="article_id"]').val();
```

If you want the 'second' input, then you can do this

```
var article_id = $(this).closest('form').find('input').eq(1).val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `eq(1)` to get the second element from the matched set of elements.

```
article_id = $('input:eq(1)',$(this).closest('form')).val();
```

Since you have an id to the input fields you can also use. The ids of elements on the page should be unique.

```
input = $("#article_id").val();
```

Comment: @David - Try my edited answer, that should work for you thanks.